# removed nib issues and calling init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

I have deleted my nib file from my UIViewController and now I want to make it so that it calls init instead of initWithNibName. However, even after I deleted my UIViewController, it is still calling the initWithNibName. What do I need to do to change this so that it calls init?

I initialized the rest of the UIViewController via code, in my UITabBarController I have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setTabURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tt://mygroup",
                      @"tt://all",
                      @"tt://search",
                      nil]];
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating your view controller? In another nib? Programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three20 framework always calls initWithNib, even if the `TTViewController` is created without a nib file.

Just move your initialization code into the `- (void)loadView` function as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter to you what `init` method is called? Just take the code you would put in `init` and put it in `initWithNibName:bundle`.

Comment: I am just curios on how this could happen

Comment: you could trace the call and see what is making it happen

Comment: someone replied above that this is the case when I use three20

Comment: not always. Many times you will be instantiating and handling `TTViewControllers yourself` There is not rule that says you have to, but in three20, it is usually easier and beneficial to work with the methods and conventions that they intended. When that isn't quite right for you, make your own accessor and init

Answer (score 0):

Find where UIViewController is being allocated and initialized and change it to init instead of initWithNib.